# Data element of the OM Node is NULL

Tags: web-services, soap, axis

When i invoke the webservice from Java program, it throws:

`javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Data element of the OM Node is NULL`

Where as the same works fine in SOAPUI. The input to the service in the plain String's. Aixs and SOAP documentation does not provide additional information.

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Data element of the OM Node is NULL
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:188)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:130)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:118)
    at $Proxy34.xcCreateDistributedSession(Unknown Source)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Code used to access the Webservice

```
private String createNewSession() {
String sessionState;
WSPortType ap = getWSPortType();
    try {
        sessionState = ap.xcCreateDistributedSession(sessionRequestParms);
    } catch(XcErrorResponseMessage e) {
        throw new YException(msg, e);
    } catch(WebServiceException e) {
        throw new RemoteAccessException(msg, e);
    }
    return sessionState;
}
```

The  WebserviceException is raised.

Comment: can you provide your tried java program?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i fixed the issue. The mandatory field is missing and the service did not handle it correctly. Due to that "Data element of the OM Node is NULL" is returned.